# Is it possible to automatically put a reference to uploaded images?

Tags: feature-request, images, attribution

Many times when answering I put some image that I found googling.

As I understand it, this requires citing the source where the image comes from. Since this is specified in the policy, wouldn't it be a nice feature to create an automatic reference to the original image when said image is embedded?

Examples (borrowed from the answer and comments):

Image description
[image: Courtesy of creativecommons.org]

Tooltip (see markdown for difference)
[image]

Superscript caption
[image]
<sup>Courtesy of creativecommons.org</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like the idea; I've often found it a pain to reference images, even though I know I really should, because there's no real standardised way of doing so and it's not automagical.

As an initial step, instead of having the rather prosaic:

```
 ![enter image description here][1]
```

, which no one bothers to do, unless for fun, you could place the image location in the box:

```
 ![Retrieved from http://burninate.com/trogdor.png 2013/11/21][1]
```

Comment: Actually I'll make it a tooltip, alt text is shown only when the image is not availale: `![][1]` and then `[1]:http://i.imgur.com/fnfUk.png "Retrieved from burninate.com/trogdor.png 2013/11/21"`. (putting `http://` breaks the markdown)

Comment: Ignore everything I've just said; I like the idea @sha.

Comment: ooooh, I never knew the tooltip tip, thanks! @ShaWizDowArd

Comment: @brasofilo actually I saw it once, loved it, but never bothered to actually check how to do that... until now. ☻

Comment: I'd prefer `<sup>putting the [link](below the question) in sup tags</sup>`

Comment: I agree with @Won't: using the tooltip makes it only visible on mouse over, while it would be clearer if it's always visible.

Comment: I'd say that the perfect post should go for it all: Alt + Tooltip + `<sup>`, each one aptly used. But, frankly, the tooltip is lovely :o)

Comment: Tooltip would be great. Would not disturb the flow of the post. No real risk of accidental deletion / move by editor. Also, using superscript for what really should be figcaption in html 5 seems little wrong. But I agree that fig+figcaption might overcomplicate syntax, so probably not worth it.

Comment: Ben, how would you raise the attention on this feature request besides a bounty?

Comment: Unfortunately not @clabacchio. There's plenty of other stuff going on so you won't necessarily get this done immediately, however much people agree with you.